# Merging two incomparable sorted lists of elements keeping their relative ordering in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random, merge

I have two ordered lists with incomparable elements:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]  
l2 = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
```

I want to merge them randomly into one list but keep their relative order, like this:

```
ml = [1, 2, obj1, obj2, 3, obj3, 4]
```

or

```
ml = [obj1, 1, 2, 3, obj2, obj3, 4]
```

I would appreciate if anyone help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Simple function that modifies the input and returns a list:

```
import random

l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = ["obj1", "obj2", "obj3"]

def merge_random(lists):
    res = []
    while lists:
        li = random.choice(lists)
        res.append(li.pop(0))
        lists = [li for li in lists if li]
    return res

print(merge_random((l1, l2)))
```

Example output:

```
['obj1', 'obj2', 1, 2, 'obj3', 3, 4]
```

### A generator, the more pythonic solution

This solution was suggested by [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements). It makes use of a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) and does not modify the user input. This is clearly the more pythonic solution to the problem.

```
import random

def f(*iterables):
    todo = [iter(it) for it in iterables]
    while todo:
        idx = random.randrange(len(todo))
        try:
            yield next(todo[idx])
        except StopIteration:
            del todo[idx]
```

It can be used like this:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = ["obj1", "obj2", "obj3"]

for i in f(l1, l2):
    print(i)
```

**Example output:**

```
obj1
1
2
obj2
obj3
3
4
```

Comment: I do not this this would work, because the result is required to have the elements in the same order as in the original lists. With your suggested code, for example 'obj2' could appear before 'obj1'

Comment: Ahh... good point... completely glossed over the "relative ordering" part... ignore me :)

Comment: You could probably generalise it something like: http://dpaste.com/1XTNTW3

Comment: Except having a generator, I do not see the big advantage over my answer. Anyway, post this as an answer and have my upvote :)

Comment: Ahh... I hadn't noticed you'd generalised it - I still saw `while l1 or l2` as your function.... so the main advantage doesn't count there... however, it does handle arbitrary numbers of *iterables* rather than relying on them being lists and having to support a `.pop` method...

Comment: ... and it does not modify the input. You should really add this as an own answer instead of this paste that gets automatically deleted in a few days.

Comment: You were here first with a perfectly good answer - quite happy for you to use the paste if you want.

Comment: Thank you, I included it into the answer.